# ArcGIS Api For Javascript Filter Features Combined With Query Features

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Iv been having trouble trying to combine the functionality between Filter by attribute and Query Features from a FeatureLayerView. Both samples are below;

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurefilter-attributes/index.html

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurelayerview-query/index.html

The aim is to apply the chosen filter (Filter feature by attribute), and this filter be applied to the Query FeatureLayerView showing in the side panel.

We have currently got both functionality working correctly in one sample, however they are still working in isolation from each other. I have added the code we have below.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #seasons-filter {
            height: 160px;
            width: 160px;
            width: 100%;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .season-item {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 40px;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .season-item:focus {
            background-color: dimgrey;
        }

        .season-item:hover {
            background-color: dimgrey;
        }

        .panel-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .panel-side {
            padding: 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            overflow: auto;
            z-index: 60;
        }

        .panel-side h3 {
            padding: 0 20px;
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        .panel-side ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .panel-side li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }

        .panel-result {
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 2px 0;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        .panel-result:hover,
        .panel-result:focus {
            color: orange;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/widgets/Expand"
        ], function(MapView, Map, FeatureLayer, Expand) {

            let floodLayerView;
            let graphics;
            const listNode = document.getElementById("nyc_graphics");

            const popupTemplate = {
                // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                title: "{NAME} in {COUNTY}",
                content: [
                    {
                        type: "fields",
                        fieldInfos: [
                            {
                                fieldName: "B12001_calc_pctMarriedE",
                                label: "% Married",
                                format: {
                                    places: 0,
                                    digitSeparator: true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };

            // flash flood warnings layer

            const layer = new FeatureLayer({
                url:
                    "https://services.arcgis.com/P3ePLMYs2RVChkJx/ArcGIS/rest/services/ACS_Marital_Status_Boundaries/FeatureServer/2",
                outFields: ["NAME", "GEOID"], // used by queryFeatures
                popupTemplate: popupTemplate
            });

            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "gray-vector",
                layers: [layer]
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                map: map,
                container: "viewDiv",
                center: [-73.95, 40.702],
                zoom: 11
            });

            const seasonsNodes = document.querySelectorAll(`.season-item`);
            const seasonsElement = document.getElementById("seasons-filter");

            // click event handler for seasons choices
            seasonsElement.addEventListener("click", filterBySeason);

            // User clicked on Winter, Spring, Summer or Fall
            // set an attribute filter on flood warnings layer view
            // to display the warnings issued in that season
            function filterBySeason(event) {
                const selectedSeason = event.target.getAttribute("data-season");
                floodLayerView.filter = {
                    where: "State = '" + selectedSeason + "'"
                };
            }

            view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView) {
                // flash flood warnings layer loaded
                // get a reference to the flood warnings layerview
                floodLayerView = layerView;

                // set up UI items
                seasonsElement.style.visibility = "visible";
                const seasonsExpand = new Expand({
                    view: view,
                    content: seasonsElement,
                    expandIconClass: "esri-icon-filter",
                    group: "top-left"
                });
                //clear the filters when user closes the expand widget
                seasonsExpand.watch("expanded", function() {
                    if (!seasonsExpand.expanded) {
                        floodLayerView.filter = null;
                    }
                });
                view.ui.add(seasonsExpand, "top-left");
            });

            // Start Of Side Bar Element

           view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView) {
                layerView.watch("updating", function(value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        // wait for the layer view to finish updating
                        // query all the features available for drawing.
                        layerView
                            .queryFeatures({
                                geometry: view.extent,
                                returnGeometry: true,
                                orderByFields: ["NAME"]
                            })
                            .then(function(results) {
                                graphics = results.features;

                                const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                                graphics.forEach(function(result, index) {
                                    const attributes = result.attributes;
                                    const name = attributes.NAME;

                                    // Create a list zip codes in NY
                                    const li = document.createElement("li");
                                    li.classList.add("panel-result");
                                    li.tabIndex = 0;
                                    li.setAttribute("data-result-id", index);
                                    li.textContent = name;

                                    fragment.appendChild(li);
                                });
                                // Empty the current list
                                listNode.innerHTML = "";
                                listNode.appendChild(fragment);
                            })
                            .catch(function(error) {
                                console.error("query failed: ", error);
                            });
                    }
                });
            });

            // listen to click event on the zip code list
            listNode.addEventListener("click", onListClickHandler);

            function onListClickHandler(event) {
                const target = event.target;
                const resultId = target.getAttribute("data-result-id");

                // get the graphic corresponding to the clicked zip code
                const result =
                    resultId && graphics && graphics[parseInt(resultId, 10)];

                if (result) {
                    // open the popup at the centroid of zip code polygon
                    // and set the popup's features which will populate popup content and title.

                    view
                        .goTo(result.geometry.extent.expand(2))
                        .then(function() {
                            view.popup.open({
                                features: [result],
                                location: result.geometry.centroid
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            if (error.name != "AbortError") {
                                console.error(error);
                            }
                        });
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is filter the graphics you obtain with the query with a simple condition. Using both examples of ArcGIS, I put together what I think you are trying to get.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>Filter and Query - 4.15</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #seasons-filter {
        height: 160px;
        width: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
      }

      .season-item {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 40px;
      }

      .season-item:focus {
        background-color: dimgrey;
      }

      .season-item:hover {
        background-color: dimgrey;
      }

      #titleDiv {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      #titleText {
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-weight: 60;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .panel-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .panel-side {
        padding: 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        overflow: auto;
        z-index: 60;
      }

      .panel-side h3 {
        padding: 0 20px;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }

      .panel-side ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .panel-side li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }

      .panel-result {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 2px 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      .panel-result:hover,
      .panel-result:focus {
        color: orange;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      require([
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Expand"
      ], function(MapView, Map, FeatureLayer, Expand) {
        const listNode = document.getElementById("list_graphics");
        const seasonsNodes = document.querySelectorAll(`.season-item`);
        const seasonsElement = document.getElementById("seasons-filter");
        let layer, map, view;
        let selectedSeason = null;
        let floodLayerView;
        let graphics = null;
        // functions
        const filterBySeason = function (event) {
          selectedSeason = event.target.getAttribute("data-season");
          floodLayerView.filter = {
            where: "Season = '" + selectedSeason + "'"
          };
          updateList();
        };
        const updateList = function () {
          if (!graphics) {
            return;
          }
          const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
          graphics.forEach(function(result, index) {
            const attributes = result.attributes;
            if (!selectedSeason || attributes.SEASON ===  selectedSeason) {
              const name = attributes.IssueDate;
              // Create the list
              const li = document.createElement("li");
              li.classList.add("panel-result");
              li.tabIndex = 0;
              li.setAttribute("data-result-id", index);
              li.textContent = name;
              fragment.appendChild(li);
            }
          });
          // Empty the current list
          listNode.innerHTML = "";
          listNode.appendChild(fragment);
        };
        // flash flood warnings layer
        layer = new FeatureLayer({
          portalItem: {
            id: "f9e348953b3848ec8b69964d5bceae02"
          },
          outFields: ["SEASON", "IssueDate"]
        });
        map = new Map({
          basemap: "gray-vector",
          layers: [layer]
        });
        view = new MapView({
          map: map,
          container: "viewDiv",
          center: [-98, 40],
          zoom: 10
        });
        // click event handler for seasons choices
        seasonsElement.addEventListener("click", filterBySeason);
        view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView) {
          /*
          
          filter
          
          */
          floodLayerView = layerView;
          // set up UI items
          seasonsElement.style.visibility = "visible";
          const seasonsExpand = new Expand({
            view: view,
            content: seasonsElement,
            expandIconClass: "esri-icon-filter",
            group: "top-left"
          });
          //clear the filters when user closes the expand widget
          seasonsExpand.watch("expanded", function() {
            if (!seasonsExpand.expanded) {
              floodLayerView.filter = null;
            }
          });
          view.ui.add(seasonsExpand, "top-left");
          view.ui.add("titleDiv", "bottom-left");

          /*

          query
          
          */
          layerView.watch("updating", function(value) {
            if (!value) {
              // wait for the layer view to finish updating
              // query all the features available for drawing.
              layerView
                .queryFeatures({
                  geometry: view.extent,
                  returnGeometry: true,
                  orderByFields: ["IssueDate"]
                })
                .then(function (results) {
                  graphics = results.features;
                  updateList();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.error("query failed: ", error);
                });
            }
          });
        });
        /*

        query
        
        */
        // listen to click event on list items
        listNode.addEventListener("click", onListClickHandler);
        function onListClickHandler(event) {
          const target = event.target;
          const resultId = target.getAttribute("data-result-id");
          // get the graphic corresponding to the clicked item
          const result =
            resultId && graphics && graphics[parseInt(resultId, 10)];
          if (result) {
            // open the popup at the centroid of polygon
            // and set the popup's features which will populate popup content and title.
            view
              .goTo(result.geometry.extent.expand(2))
              .then(function() {
                view.popup.open({
                  features: [result],
                  location: result.geometry.centroid
                });
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                if (error.name != "AbortError") {
                  console.error(error);
                }
              });
          }
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel-container">
      <div id="seasons-filter" class="esri-widget">
        <div class="season-item visible-season" data-season="Winter">Winter</div>
        <div class="season-item visible-season" data-season="Spring">Spring</div>
        <div class="season-item visible-season" data-season="Summer">Summer</div>
        <div class="season-item visible-season" data-season="Fall">Fall</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-side esri-widget">
        <ul id="list_graphics">
          <li>Loading&hellip;</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="viewDiv"></div>
      <div id="titleDiv" class="esri-widget">
        <div id="titleText">Flash Floods by Season</div>
        <div>Flash Flood Warnings (2002 - 2012)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just move things a bit so that each time the user filter with the seasons the list of the side panel is updated.
Now, you will see that I do not query on a new season, I just filter the graphics that we already have.
Each time a new query is made, the list is going to filter in the same manner.

Comment: Glad it helps you!

Answer (score -1):

Im also trying to add an option within the dropdown list to clear or filters and reset the side panel. I have added an on-click event, which clears the filters, but it doesn't reset the side panel.

Any help would be much appreciated.

````
        require([
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/widgets/Expand"
        ], function(MapView, Map, FeatureLayer, Expand) {
            const listNode = document.getElementById("list_graphics");
            const seasonsNodes = document.querySelectorAll(`.season-item`);
            const seasonsElement = document.getElementById("seasons-filter");
            let layer, map, view;
            let selectedSeason = null;
            let floodLayerView;
            let graphics = null;
            // functions
            const filterBySeason = function (event) {
                selectedSeason = event.target.getAttribute("data-season");
                floodLayerView.filter = {
                    where: "Season = '" + selectedSeason + "'"
                };
                document
                    .getElementById("filterReset")
                    .addEventListener("click", function() {
                        floodLayerView.filter = selectedSeason;
                    });

                updateList();
            };
            const updateList = function () {
                if (!graphics) {
                    return;
                }
                const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                graphics.forEach(function(result, index) {
                    const attributes = result.attributes;
                    if (!selectedSeason || attributes.SEASON ===  selectedSeason) {
                        const name = attributes.IssueDate;
                        // Create the list
                        const li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.classList.add("panel-result");
                        li.tabIndex = 0;
                        li.setAttribute("data-result-id", index);
                        li.textContent = name;
                        fragment.appendChild(li);
                    }
                });
                // Empty the current list
                listNode.innerHTML = "";
                listNode.appendChild(fragment);
            };
            // flash flood warnings layer
            layer = new FeatureLayer({
                portalItem: {
                    id: "f9e348953b3848ec8b69964d5bceae02"
                },
                outFields: ["SEASON", "IssueDate"]
            });
            map = new Map({
                basemap: "gray-vector",
                layers: [layer]
            });
            view = new MapView({
                map: map,
                container: "viewDiv",
                center: [-98, 40],
                zoom: 10
            });
            // click event handler for seasons choices
            seasonsElement.addEventListener("click", filterBySeason);
            view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView) {
                /*

                filter

                */
                floodLayerView = layerView;
                // set up UI items
                seasonsElement.style.visibility = "visible";
                const seasonsExpand = new Expand({
                    view: view,
                    content: seasonsElement,
                    expandIconClass: "esri-icon-filter",
                    group: "top-left"
                });
                //clear the filters when user closes the expand widget

                view.ui.add(seasonsExpand, "top-left");
                view.ui.add("titleDiv", "bottom-left");

                /*

                query

                */
                layerView.watch("updating", function(value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        // wait for the layer view to finish updating
                        // query all the features available for drawing.
                        layerView
                            .queryFeatures({
                                geometry: view.extent,
                                returnGeometry: true,
                                orderByFields: ["IssueDate"]
                            })
                            .then(function (results) {
                                graphics = results.features;
                                updateList();
                            })
                            .catch(function(error) {
                                console.error("query failed: ", error);
                            });
                    }
                });
            });
            /*

            query

            */
            // listen to click event on list items
            listNode.addEventListener("click", onListClickHandler);
            function onListClickHandler(event) {
                const target = event.target;
                const resultId = target.getAttribute("data-result-id");
                // get the graphic corresponding to the clicked item
                const result =
                    resultId && graphics && graphics[parseInt(resultId, 10)];
                if (result) {
                    // open the popup at the centroid of polygon
                    // and set the popup's features which will populate popup content and title.
                    view
                        .goTo(result.geometry.extent.expand(2))
                        .then(function() {
                            view.popup.open({
                                features: [result],
                                location: result.geometry.centroid
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            if (error.name != "AbortError") {
                                console.error(error);
                            }
                        });
                }
            };
        });
    </script>```
````

Comment: You should create a new post for this question